# Selenium problem with ElementClickInterceptedException

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I am trying to scraping in this URL, dealing with a Download button and I am having a problem, as the last line gives a `ElementClickInterceptedException`.
My actual goal is to download the CSV file.

The code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver_path = 'C:\\Users\\Idener\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, options=options)
url = "https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/2078"
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="NIOSH-Toxicity-Data"]/div[1]/div/div/a'))).click()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="Download"]'))).click()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6T8tx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Element you trying to click in initially out of the visible viewpoint. So, you need first to scroll the page and only then to click on that element.
2. By clicking the first element new tab is opened and the second element you want to click is there, on the second tab. So, you need to switch to the new tab to access that element.
3. No need to define `wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)` second time.
   The following code is working:

```py
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = "https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/2078#section=Toxicity"

driver.get(url)
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#NIOSH-Toxicity-Data a[title*='Open']")))
element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
time.sleep(1)
element.click()
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "Download"))).click()
```

It does not download the file, only opens the downloading dialog
[image]

Comment: driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service) 

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service'

Comment: By running that code, just changing the path I obtained that error

Comment: May it be the version of selenium?

Comment: You can try using your original approach here `driver_path = 'C:\\Users\\Idener\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe'` , `driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, options=options)`